# SharePoint-Progammatically create a folder using non administrator account in c#

Tags: development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SharePoint -access to path is denied](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54607/sharepoint-access-to-path-is-denied)

I am working in SharePoint 2010,C#. I need to create a folder in my system using a sharepoint non administrator account. For example: storing the document from sharepoint document library in a folder inside D:\ drive.

```
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath,securityRules);
```

here securityRules has full control to the sharepoint logged-in user.

The problem is when the logged-in user is non administrataor then the folder is not created(access to path is denied). But administrator account works fine. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this?