# Restrict permissions/access to list items in code

Tags: development, permissions, security, .net, inheritance

Does anyone know a way to restrict access to list items in code, even if someone has full control on a list item, deny that in code.

I know there is a way for updating using event receiver, but I'm looking for a way to do it for viewing items too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,make sure to break the inheritance(should have unique permissions).

```
 SPRoleAssignment roleassignment_group = new SPRoleAssignment(group or user);

SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);

roleassignment_group.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
//Here we are checking if inheriting from parent.If it is break the inheritance.
if (!myList.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    myList.BreakRoleInheritance(true); 
} 
myList.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
myList.Update();
```

[how to give Role permission to list programmatically?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54824/how-to-give-role-permission-to-list-programmatically)

Comment: sorry Amit this isn't what i'm looking for, i want to intercept the permissions, even if they have full control i want to be able to stop read access using a custom security model. ie a list that has users in it with items they can't read.