# WSS 3.0 Contributor Permissions can't delete folders

Tags: development, wss-3.0

```
SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    SPSite siteColl = SPContext.Current.Site;
                    SPWeb webSite = siteColl.OpenWeb();

                    int getIDProjectList = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

                    SPListItem attachmentToDelete = webSite.Lists["Projects List"].GetItemById(getIDProjectList);

                    SPFolder folders = attachmentToDelete.ParentList.RootFolder.SubFolders["AttachmentFiles"];
                    folders.SubFolders[getIDProjectList.ToString()].Delete();
                    folders.Update();

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            ValidateFormDigest();
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPSite siteColl = SPContext.Current.Site;
                SPWeb webSite = siteColl.OpenWeb();
                int getIDProjectList = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

                SPListItem attachmentToDelete = webSite.Lists["Projects List"].GetItemById(getIDProjectList);

                webSite.Folders[attachmentToDelete].SubFolders.Delete(getIDProjectList.ToString());
            });
```

Use the SPWeb object to delet the folder, using above code!

Comment: I tried the code below and get an Access Denied under Contributor Permissions.  This works under Owner Permissions. webSite.Folders["Lists"].SubFolders["Projects"].SubFolders["AttachmentFiles"].SubFolders.Delete(getIDProjectList.ToString());

Comment: if you want the person to delete the folder than you can encapsulate it with an impersonation which will do the trick for you! checkout my answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54607/sharepoint-access-to-path-is-denied

Comment: Thanks @ali Sharepoint.  This worked!  The only thing I had to add was a 'website.AllowUnsafeUndates=true' because when i ran your suggested code, I got a 'security validation for this page is invalid....' message.

Comment: thats no problem happy to help! just remember once you have done the update to set website.AllowUnsafeUndates = false; ;) , also please mark this as an answer for other people with the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is here
`folders.SubFolders[getIDProjectList.ToString()].Delete();`
It's strange behavior for me to delete a folder using ID of listitem such as number of element in collection.